# Migrate Data: MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am currently in a task where I need to move the data from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I have 2000 rows of data mostly from 2 out of 50 tables in MySQL DB. I'm using mysql connector and psycopg2 for the tasks.

The tables and columns per table in destination DB is very different from the source DB so I need to dissect some data from source DB before moving it to destination DB. To achieve this I am using a for loop.

I stumbled on this thread which is similar to my situation: [MySQL-to-PostgreSQL migration script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107289/mysql-to-postgresql-migration-script). It was stated there that it's not good to use for loop. I would like to know, should I stick to for loop or look for another way of approach to the task?

Comment: CSV export-import is not the option?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I am newbie to this so please bear with me, is there a way to modify the values in CSV before exporting or importing? Like I want the names to be migrated as firstname, middlename, lastname since from source DB its only name.

Comment: The common way is to create intermediate database on the source server then copy/transform data from the original database and then export intermediate data in the server-independent format.

Comment: *is there a way to modify the values in CSV before exporting or importing?* There is a way to modify values during export. MySQL `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` allows to use any semantically correct expressions in the SELECT clause, so You can modify data as You need, including combine data from a lot of tables (using a list of joined tables in FROM clause) in one output file make it matched the destination structure. Sometimes this process may need in additional static tables - for example, while dividing one table to two tables with the aim of data normalizing.

Comment: if you only have 2000 rows, a for loop will be fine.  unless you need this to run in 50ms instead of 50s.